# xtext - Couldn't resolve reference to

Tags: xtext, cross-reference

I have the following grammar:

```
Model: prog+=Program*;

Program: g=Greeting  de+=DataEntry* s+=Statement*;

Greeting: 'Hello' t=ProgPara '!';

ProgPara: 'PROGRAM'  pname=Progname ';';

Progname : name=ID;

DataEntry:  a=INT v=Varname ';';   

Varname : name = ID;

Statement: (c=CopyStmt|m=MoveStmt) ';';

CopyStmt: 'COPY' 'TO' qname=[IndexVarname|ID] ;

IndexVarname : (Indexname|Varname);   

Indexname : '(' name = ID ')';

MoveStmt: 'MOVE' 'TO' p=[PrVarName|ID];

PrVarName : (Varname|Progname);
```

But it throws error for:

```
PrVarName : (Varname|Progname);
```

So i modified the grammar to have as below:

```
PrVarName : (v=Varname|Progname);
```

I updated the Scope provider as below:

```
override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    if (context instanceof CopyStmt) {
        if (reference.featureID == TestDslPackage.COPY_STMT__QNAME) {
            val rootElement = EcoreUtil2.getRootContainer(context);
            val candidates1 = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, Indexname);
            val candidates2 = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, Varname);
            val candidates = candidates1 + candidates2;

            return Scopes.scopeFor(candidates);
        }
    } else if (context instanceof MoveStmt) {
        if (reference.featureID == TestDslPackage.MOVE_STMT__P) {
            val rootElement = EcoreUtil2.getRootContainer(context);
            val candidates1 = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, Progname);
            val candidates2 = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, Varname);
            val candidates = candidates1 + candidates2;

            return Scopes.scopeFor(candidates);
        }
    }       
}
```

Once the grammar was built and i ran the below test case, it is throwing error in the MOVE statement saying "Couldn't resolve reference to PrVarName 'test1'."

```
Hello PROGRAM test;!

1 test1;
2 test2;
3 test3;

COPY TO test2;
MOVE TO test1;
```

Looks like i cannot use Varname in two different cross references. But there is a very valid need for it. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain what all the name types you have do. where are Indexnames declared. why dont you simply reference a Progname or Varname only

Comment: One of the grammar lines should have had the indexName like `DataEntry:  a=INT v=Varname ';';` No only variable names and program names need to appear in certain scenarios. In some other scenarios only variable names and index names need to appear. Hence the differenciation.

Comment: It it does not. If I can’t reproduce ...

Comment: sorry didn't get you. there is error marking in the sample program on test1. Can you share the mwe2 file in case it is not showing error?

Comment: Please share your complete grammar. The one you had is not

Comment: The rule `DataEntry: a=INT v=Varname ';';` should be `DataEntry:
    a=INT (v=Varname| in=Indexname) ';'; `

Comment: This is my complete grammar. `Model:
 prog+=Program*;

Program: g=Greeting  de+=DataEntry* s+=Statement*;

Greeting:
 'Hello' t=ProgPara '!';

ProgPara
   : 'PROGRAM'  pname=Progname ';';

Progname : name=ID;

DataEntry:
    a=INT (v=Varname| in=Indexname) ';';   

Varname : name = ID;

Statement: (c=CopyStmt|m=MoveStmt) ';';

CopyStmt: 'COPY' 'TO' qname=[IndexVarname|ID] ;

IndexVarname : (Indexname|Varname);   

Indexname : '(' name = ID ')';
 
MoveStmt: 'MOVE' 'TO' p=[PrVarName|ID];

PrVarName : p=(Progname|Varname);`

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PrVarName : p=(Progname|Varname);
```

is bad cause it changes the type hierarchy. Progname and Varname are no longer subtypes of PrVarName. By reverting the change and introducing a common Named supertype you can resolve this

```
Model:
    prog+=Program*;

Program:
    g=Greeting de+=DataEntry* s+=Statement*;

Greeting:
    'Hello' t=ProgPara '!';

ProgPara:
    'PROGRAM' pname=Progname ';';

DataEntry:
    a=INT (v=Varname | in=Indexname) ';';

Statement:
    (c=CopyStmt | m=MoveStmt) ';';

CopyStmt:
    'COPY' 'TO' qname=[IndexVarname|ID];

MoveStmt:
    'MOVE' 'TO' p=[PrVarName|ID];

PrVarName:
    Progname | Varname;

IndexVarname:
    (Indexname | Varname);

Named:Progname|Indexname|Varname;   

Progname:
    {Progname} name=ID; 

Indexname:
    {Indexname}'(' name=ID ')';

Varname:
    {Varame}name=ID;
```

Comment: Thanks Christian. This helped.