# Cross referencing in Xtext is very slow. How do i improve it?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

This is in continuation with the issue mentioned in the forum:
[xtext-Couldn't-resolve-reference-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417819/xtext-couldnt-resolve-reference-to).

The sample model i am using is as below

```
grammar org.xtext.example.testdsl.TestDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
generate testDsl "http://www.test.com/test/example/TestDsl"

Model:
prog+=Program*;

Program: g=Greeting  de+=DataEntry* s+=Statement*;
Greeting: 'Hello' t=ProgPara '!';
ProgPara: 'PROGRAM'  pname=Progname ';';
Progname : name=ID;

DataEntry:  a=INT (v=Varname| in=Indexname) ';';   
Varname : name = ID;

Statement: c=CopyStmt ';';
CopyStmt: 'COPY' 'TO' qname=[IndexVarname|ID] ;
IndexVarname : (Indexname|Varname);   
Indexname : '(' name = ID ')';

Named:Progname|Indexname|Varname;
```

I have a file which uses similar grammar and this file is pretty big with about 12000 lines of code and 2000 odd Progname or Varname and at each instance it is trying to resolve the type in the scope provider. The grammar has about 326 elements in it.

```
 val candidates1 = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, Indexname);
 val candidates2 = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, Varname);
 val candidates = candidates1 + candidates2;
 return Scopes.scopeFor(candidates);
```

Because of repeated calls to ***getScope()***, the file is taking for ever to open in Editor. Even if it opens any small edit is way too slow. Please suggest how i could resolve this issue.

I tried adding caching support for the above code as below:

```
class TestDslScopeProvider extends AbstractTestDslScopeProvider {
  @Inject
    IResourceScopeCache cache;

  override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    if (context instanceof CopyStmt) {
        if (reference.featureID == TestDslPackage.COPY_STMT__QNAME) {
            val candidates = cache.get(
                context,
                reference.eResource,
                [|findQNameCandidates(context, reference)]
            );
            return Scopes.scopeFor(candidates);
        }   
      }
      return super.getScope(context, reference);        
  }

  def findQNameCandidates(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    val rootElement = EcoreUtil2.getRootContainer(context);
    val candidates1 = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, Indexname);
    val candidates2 = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, Varname);
    return candidates1 + candidates2;
  }
}
```

Even now, it is still very slow. There has been no difference.  If i replace the context with reference object as key for the cache, then the speed is fast but then all cross referenced links are lost and I get errors. I am not able to point where i am not doing the right thing.

Thanks,
Anitha

Comment: is there a reason you do this with custom scoping and not default? how big is your ast? depending on the situation it might be easier to collect the elements by going to them explicitely e.g. model.getX and model.getY

additionally you could look at the IResourceScopeCache

Comment: I have been trying your suggestion with IResourceScopeCache, but looks like i am doing something wrong here. I modified the above code to look like `val candidates1 = cache.get(Indexname, context.eResource, [|evaluate(rootElement, Indexname)]);
     val candidates2 = cache.get(Varname, context.eResource, [|evaluate(rootElement, Varname)]);
     val candidates = candidates1 + candidates2;
      return Scopes.scopeFor(candidates);`   However, i am not getting any data out of this. What am i doing wrong? Should I bind the cache?

Comment: I don’t understand what evaluate does. Did you debug that code.

Comment: evaluate is defined as  `def evaluate(EObject rootElement, Class element) {
  
  return EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, element);
 }`. Tried debugging, but sometimes even the control is not coming into getScope method. Slightly confused with this behavior.

Comment: how did you define the. Ethos

Comment: Sorry Christian. I did not get what you meant by Ethos. I have updated the questions with all the details. Am i passing the right key and resource to the cache or is there something wrong in this logic?

Comment: sorry typo on mobile. should be method

Comment: I modified my code as below and it is very fast now.
`override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
  if (context instanceof CopyStmt) {
    if (reference.featureID == MyDslPackage.QNAME) {
      val candidates = cache.get(reference, reference.eResource, [|findQnameCandidates(context, reference)]);
      return Scopes.scopeFor(candidates, true);
    }
  }
  return super.getScope(context, reference);
}
`

Comment: `def findQNameCandidates(EObject rootElement, Class element) {
    val rootElement = EcoreUtil2.getRootContainer(context);
   val candidates1 = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, Indexname);
   val candidates2 = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, Varname);

   return candidates1 + candidates2;
}`
However cross reference does not work and i see errors for all items.If i replace replace the cache key from reference to context, it resolves the errors but speed goes back to it's original self.  Any suggestions to resolve both now?

Comment: can you please create a simple hello world project and share your code

Comment: I have updated the problem statement with the issue. I have provided the grammar and scope provider code. Sample test code is as below:                                                       `Hello PROGRAM test;!

1 test1;
2 (test2);
3 test3;

COPY TO test2;`                                                                                                             However this will not show any performance issue. you'll need bigger set for hitting the performance issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following works for me

```
@Inject
IResourceScopeCache cache;

override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    if (context instanceof CopyStmt) {
        if (reference.featureID == MyDslPackage.COPY_STMT__QNAME) {
            val candidates = cache.get(
                "COPY_STMT__QNAME_scope",
                context.eResource,
                [|findQNameCandidates(context, reference)]
            );
            return Scopes.scopeFor(candidates);
        }
    }
    return super.getScope(context, reference);
}

def findQNameCandidates(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    val rootElement = EcoreUtil2.getRootContainer(context);
    val candidates1 = EcoreUtil2.getAllContentsOfType(rootElement, IndexVarname);
    return candidates1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian. The above solution was giving an issue if I have more than one file, now i have added a file id also for caching and after this, it works fine.

Comment: I don’t understand. What do you mean by fileid and working with. More than one file. All you posted so far excludes that

Comment: I added a rule for having file ids to help in this.